# ¿Cuál es el origen de "samuelear"?

Tags: etimología, verbos, costa-rica

En el Diccionario de la lengua española se recoge [**samuelear**](https://dle.rae.es/samuelear) como:

> 1. tr. coloq. *C. Rica*. p. us. Dicho de un hombre: Observar furtivamente o con disimulo las partes sexuales de una persona, en especial de una mujer.

y dos entradas relacionadas:

[**samuel**](https://dle.rae.es/samuel?):

> 1. m. C. Rica. Acción de samuelear.
>
> **echar un samuel**
>
> 1. loc. verb. *C. Rica*. samuelear.

y [**samueleador**](https://dle.rae.es/samueleador?):

> 1. m. *C. Rica*. p. us. Hombre que tiene por costumbre samuelear.

Las tres entradas son exclusivas de *C. Rica*, pero no hay ninguna indicación acerca de su origen. ¿Cuál es el origen de "samuelear"?

Comment: http://puesfijate.blogspot.com/2009/03/samuelear.html

Answer (score 2):

Mira el número 17 en [esta página web](https://conozcasucanton.com/noticias/asi-se-dice-en-costa-rica-origen-de-los-dichos-ticos-5101/)

> 17. **Samuelear, samueliar**
>
> *Significado:* Acción de voyeurismo, ver las prendas íntimas, órganos sexuales o actos íntimos de otras personas.
>
> *Origen:* En Paso Ancho, antes de los años 1950, vivía un señor llamado don Samuel, en un cuarto destartalado y lleno de hendijas. Un grupo de niñas acostumbraba ir a fisgonearlo cuando llegaba por las tardes y se desnudaba. De allí sacaron la expresión: “Vamos a samueliar”. La expresión se extendió y, a partir de allí, a los que gustan de ver personas desnudas o partes de su cuerpo o de su ropa, se les empezó a llamar “samueleadores.”

y

> Seguimos leyendo y nos enteramos de que la palabra procede un tal Samuel que vivía en la localidad de Cartago (de Costa Rica, no la de Aníbal) a principios de siglo (entendemos, del XX), muy aficionado al asunto.

(obtenido de [aquí](http://puesfijate.blogspot.com/2009/03/samuelear.html))

y más

> **samuelear**
> El termino samuelear proviene de una historia en un pueblo cualquiera de un señor que se dedicaba a intentar ver las partes intimas de las señoras. Resulta que aquel señor se llamaba Samuel y de aquel nombre se construyó el verbo samuelear. Aunque samuelear no esta muy extendido ya que para definir lo mismo se ha impuesto una palabra que proviene del frances, voyeur."

(obtenido de [aquí](https://www.significadode.org/samuelear.htm))